# Ant Problem deploying field on custom metadata type

Tags: ant, migration-tool, custom-metadata

I am trying to deploy a field on a custom metadata type using Ant.

Here's my `package.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomMetadata</name>
    </types>
    <version>43.0</version>
</Package>
```

Then inside a `customMetadata` folder I have a file called `nameOfMtdType.NameOfField.md`. That file's content looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomMetadata xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <values>
        <fullName>Number_Of_Balls__c</fullName>
        <description>The maximum number of balls that are allowed.</description>
        <externalId>false</externalId>
        <fieldManageability>DeveloperControlled</fieldManageability>
        <inlineHelpText>The maximum number of balls that are allowed.</inlineHelpText>
        <label>Number Of Balls</label>
        <precision>4</precision>
        <required>false</required>
        <scale>0</scale>
        <type>Number</type>
        <unique>false</unique>
    </values>
</CustomMetadata>
```

I am getting this error: `Error parsing file: Element {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}fullName invalid at this location in type CustomMetadataValue`

What am I doing wrong? The content inside the `<values></values>` is what I pulled from my scratch org using sfdx.

Also, I was trying to follow the documentation from this link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_custommetadata.htm

Is there a better resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Metadata API type `CustomMetadata` is for deploying *records* of Custom Metadata Types, not the schema of the type itself. That's why you're getting back that error - you supplied part of the type definition where Salesforce was looking for record data.

The Custom Metadata Type itself, along with its fields, is deployed as a [`CustomObject`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_custommetadatatypes.htm), where properties like `fullName` are expected. There's an example in that documentation of what it looks like to deploy a Custom Metadata Type field for a type called `ReusablePicklistOption__mdt`:

### `ReusablePicklistOption__mdt.object`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <fields>
      <fullName>AlphaSort__c</fullName>
      <defaultValue>false</defaultValue>
      <externalId>false</externalId>
      <label>Sorted Alphabetically</label>
      <type>Checkbox</type>
   </fields>
   <label>Reusable Picklist</label>
   <pluralLabel>Reusable Picklist</pluralLabel>
   <visibility>Public</visibility>
</CustomObject>
```

The easiest way to handle this, though, is just to let Salesforce DX convert the source for you with the `force:source:convert` command. You can then trim the converted Metadata API source and `package.xml` down to deploy just the elements you're interested in, like this single field.

Comment: Thanks for the sfdx convert command, that's exactly what I used and then just deployed it using ant to the appropriate org. Saved me a ton of time!